# SQL Server stored procedure based on PIVOT and parameterized query not sorting properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, stored-procedures, pivot

I am using a SQL Server stored procedure to generate a data table I use as a datasource for a WPF datagrid. The data are in two tables of parent [Sample] child [SampleConstituent] relationship and I am using a PIVOT to generate columns for the data records in the child table. The query uses parameters so that I can filter the records returned to the datagrid.

My problem is that I would like to return a TOP N result set from the query based on the most recent records. I have the following stored procedure and everything works except the data are always returned oldest records first. The `TOP N` filter is thus returning the oldest records and not the most recent. `Sample.SampleDateTime` is the column in the parent table I wish to sort by.

I have tried so many iterations that my novice brain is in knots!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSampleDisplayAllParams] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@fromDate DATE = '2013-01-01', 
@toDate DATE = '2100-01-01',
@ProductName NVARCHAR(50) = '%',
@SampleNumber NVARCHAR(50) = '%',
@numSamples NVARCHAR(50) = 200
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ConstituentName) 
                from SampleConstituent
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT @cols

set @query 
  = 'SELECT top (' + @numSamples + ') * from  
     (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT  s.SampleID, s.SampleNumber, s.SampleDateTime, s.ProductName, sc.ConstituentName, sc.ConstituentValue
FROM         dbo.Sample s INNER JOIN
                  dbo.SampleConstituent sc ON s.SampleID = sc.SampleID
WHERE (s.Active = 1) AND 
(s.ProductName Like  ''' + @ProductName + ''') AND
(s.SampleNumber Like  ''' + @SampleNumber + ''') AND
(s.SampleDateTime BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(24), @FromDate, 121) +''' AND'''+     CONVERT(nvarchar(24), @ToDate, 121) +''')
ORDER BY s.SampleDateTime        )     x
     pivot 
     (
        max(ConstituentValue)
        for ConstituentName in (' + @cols + ')
     ) p  '

execute(@query)
END
```

Comment: I have tried both ORDER BY s.SampleDateTime DESC and ASC FYI

Comment: Why is @numSamples NVARCHAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting order by after the pivot :

```
)     x
 pivot 
 (
    max(ConstituentValue)
    for ConstituentName in (' + @cols + ')
 ) p  ORDER BY SampleDateTime        '
```

for more clarification your query should look something like this:

```
 set @query 
= 'SELECT top (' + @numSamples + ') * from  
   (SELECT s.SampleID, s.SampleNumber, s.SampleDateTime, s.ProductName, sc.ConstituentName, sc.ConstituentValue
FROM         dbo.Sample s INNER JOIN
             dbo.SampleConstituent sc ON s.SampleID = sc.SampleID
WHERE (s.Active = 1) AND 
(s.ProductName Like  ''' + @ProductName + ''') AND
(s.SampleNumber Like  ''' + @SampleNumber + ''') AND
(s.SampleDateTime BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(24), @FromDate, 121) +''' AND'''+         CONVERT(nvarchar(24), @ToDate, 121) +''')
)     x
   pivot 
   (
      max(ConstituentValue)
      for ConstituentName in (' + @cols + ')
   ) p ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC'
--sort and order is placed after the pivot
```

Comment: +1 this is the right answer. I've added an answer not to compete but just to add supplemental information.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I tried the above as well as Sample.SampleDateTime and dbo.Sample.SampleDateTime and get 
"The multi-part identifier "Sample.SampleDateTime" could not be bound."

I need the sort before the TOP N filter.  I thus thought the ORDER BY had to work on the inside Select query.  ?

Comment: In that case please try using: ) p ORDER BY SampleDateTime' i.e. without s.

Comment: Hello @Sonam - getting closer!  SampleDateTime without the s works to sort the final result record set and I need this.  However my query is still returning the TOP N oldest records and I need the TOP N most recent ones.  Thanks again!

Comment: ORDER BY SampleDateTime desc

Comment: Thank you @Sonam! Works! This was my first ever post after learning so much from all the other posts on this and other sites.  I just could not get the last bit on my own and was only confusing myself more.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your order by is inside with the TOP 100 PERCENT. In this case, the ORDER BY is used to dictate which rows to include, but since you said you want all of them, SQL Server is clever and throws out both the TOP and the ORDER BY. Look at the plan, I bet there is no sort anywhere. This:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT something FROM somewhere ORDER BY something) AS x;
```

Is the *exact same* as:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT something FROM somewhere) AS x;
```

In neither case is SQL Server told to order the *end result* by anything. So it doesn't, and instead chooses an ordering which is most efficient rather than trying to read your mind.

If you want to sort, you need to put it on the outermost query, as @Sonam has identified. Some background info here:

- [Bad habits to kick : relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)

And FYI, you should do your best to guard yourself from SQL injection and use proper, parameterized queries. Again, not to take anything from @Sonam's answer, but this would be better as:

```
SELECT @sql = N'SELECT TOP (@numSamples) * FROM 
(
  SELECT s.SampleID, s.SampleNumber, s.SampleDateTime, 
         s.ProductName, sc.ConstituentName, sc.ConstituentValue
  FROM dbo.Sample AS s 
  INNER JOIN dbo.SampleConstituent AS sc 
  ON s.SampleID = sc.SampleID
  WHERE (s.Active = 1) AND 
  (s.ProductName LIKE @ProductName) AND
  (s.SampleNumber LIKE @SampleNumber) AND
  (s.SampleDateTime >= @FromDate AND s.SampleDateTime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate)
) AS x
PIVOT
(
  MAX(ConstituentValue) FOR ConstituentName IN (' + @cols + ')
) AS p
ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC;';

DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@numSamples INT, @fromDate DATE, ' +
  '@toDate DATE, @ProductName NVARCHAR(50), @SampleNumber NVARCHAR(50)';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @numSamples, @fromDate, @toDate,
  @ProductName, @SampleNumber;
```

Note that your creation of `@cols` may include constituent names that don't appear in the table in the date range you selected (or with the other parts of the where clause), so if you don't want a bunch of columns with `NULL` values for every date selected, you may want to add some of those criteria to that query as well.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - I have removed the TOP 100 PERCENT from @Sonam's response and still get the same error I identified above.  ??

Also I want to use ORDER BY or sorting both for the final display order as well as to order the records before filtering by the TOP N statement - like the example in your article.  How can I do both?

Comment: @user2755241 I don't understand why you need to use TOP and ORDER BY twice. If the inner query is selecting 100 PERCENT of the rows in the table, what is that ORDER BY doing? Nothing.